# How to copy Unix file path in OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

When I try to get the path of a file using <kbd>⌘ (Command)</kbd>+<kbd>`I`</kbd>, it gives the path in a different way.

I see this only after updating to Yosemite. It is not a text. How do I get it in the format `/Users/Myself/Documents/…`?

[image]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just select the file itself in Finder and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> or go to *Edit » Copy*.  You can then paste the path directly to a terminal window.

Note that this will escape special characters.

If you want the path in human-readable form, you need to do the following:

- Open *Utilities/Automator.app*
- Create a new *Service*
- Set it to receive *no input* from *Finder.app*
- Drag *Run AppleScript* from the left pane to the right
- Paste the following into the field:

  ```
  tell application "Finder"
      set sel to the selection as text
      set the clipboard to POSIX path of sel
  end tell
  ```
- It should look like this:

  [image]
- Save the service under any name you like, e.g. *Copy human-readable path*.

This is part one. Now, set a keyboard shortcut:

- Head to * » System Preferences » Keyboard » Shortcuts*
- Go to the *Services* section and scroll down
- Set a keyboard shortcut  for your service

  [image]

Et voilà, now press that shorcut when you need the path of any selected Finder item.

Comment: thank you man. I think it's unacceptable (especially by apple) that someone like me has to waste time to find out a way to copy a file path in 2014!!!

Comment: This is very helpful! However how do i get it to appear in my shortcuts list as its not there. (saved it as a service). Does it need to be in a particular location?

Comment: @danielCrabbe It should be saved in `~/Library/Services`, I think. [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) may help you if the default shortcut preferences do not work.

Comment: @slhck - thanks. Just seemed to take a few minutes to appear!

Comment: I wish this worked for pasting into Finder's `Go to Folder…` (`command-shift-g`).

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly with the copy-paste to the term !!

Comment: What a relief! Dealing with the file inspector for soo many years and to realize this is so easy to do. Fantastic answer.

Comment: I think it's important to mention that there are many shortcuts that are already occupied by the system. The system shortcuts **override** the user shortcuts and there is no warning when this is the case. I tried three different shortcuts and it didn't work (Shift+Cmd+7, Shift+Cmd+P, Shift+Cmd+C). So make sure you try out a variety of shortcuts before resigning...

Comment: I made a better Automator workflow, which does accept input from Finder and therefore will properly be available/unavailable depending on what you're doing in Finder: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/147461/screenshots/Screen%20Shot%202015-06-21%20at%204.53.40%20pm.png

Comment: does not work for other terminals such as Iterm2/3...

Comment: @MichaelTrouw I'm not sure what you mean. This doesn't have anything to do with the terminal – it's an automator action that can be run everywhere. Did you mean to comment on JakeGould's answer below?

Comment: @slhck meant to react to this: "Just select the file itself in Finder and press CmdC or go to Edit » Copy. You can then paste the path directly to a terminal window."

Comment: @MichaelTrouw Actually, it works for iTerm2 too – copy the file in Finder, then paste it into the terminal window. It'll show a normal Unix-style path.

Comment: WTH? it does work... funny, yesterday I tried it multiple times and it didn't. Software be weird... thanks! @slhck

Comment: The paste operation also works in TextWrangler, and BBedit.

Answer (score 13):

Open up the “Terminal” in `Applications > Utilities > Terminal` and then drag the file into the window. The full Unix path of the file will show up.

Comment: I already mentioned that in my answer. The problem is that the OP doesn't want an escaped path, I guess.

Comment: Yeah, it's a little inconvenient. I don't use this Mac for "production" anymore, but I keep discovering minor changes that makes it feel like I should've stayed with 10.9 for a little longer.

Answer (score 3):

Right-click (or control-click) on the file icon, then hold down the option key. In the pop-up menu that appears there will be a "Copy *"filename"* as Pathname" menu item. That menu item will put the POSIX path to the item on the clipboard.

Comment: According to http://osxdaily.com/2015/11/05/copy-file-path-name-text-mac-os-x-finder/ This became available with version OS X 10.11

Comment: @TecBrat Yeah, this might not be in Yosemite, but it is available now.

Answer (score 1):

Drag the file into textEdit to get the path.

Dragging the file into Terminal will replace spaces or special characters in the file name with backslashes.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "random forward slashes"? When you drag the file to a Terminal window, and the file has spaces in it (or other special characters), those will be escaped for the shell with backslashes, e.g. `foo bar` will be converted to `foo\ bar`.

Answer (score -1):

Navigate to the file.
Copy the file (Cmd+C).
Open TextEdit or Notes.
Paste (Cmd+V).

Magic!

Comment: This does not copy the path, but just the filename. The application that you paste to implements this behavior, and only Terminal seems to paste the full path (escaped though).